# Python URL Request Yahoo API

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I wrote this script that uses ystockquote-master to scrape the Yahoo Finance API for price and market cap. It is very simple and works well on my pc, however when I try to use it on my friends mac I get an error. It is a very long one so I will post it at the end. I have been struggling to find out what is going on, so hence I turned here. Background: Beginner to Novice. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
try:
    # py3
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # py2
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
    from urllib import urlencode

def _request(symbol, stat):
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=%s' % (symbol, stat)
    req = Request(url)
    resp = urlopen(req)
    return str(resp.read().decode('utf-8').strip())
def get_price(symbol):
    return _request(symbol, 'l1')
def get_market_cap(symbol):
    return _request(symbol, 'j1')

i = 0
while i<len(NewSymbolsList):
    results = open("intermediateresults.csv", "a")
    api = [get_price(NewSymbolsList[i]),get_market_cap(NewSymbolsList[i])]
    api = re.sub("\[\'|\'|\]", "", str(api))
    results.write(str(NewSymbolsList[i]) +"," +str(api) +"\n")
    print NewSymbolsList[i], api                  
    i+=1
results.close()
```

Here is the error I get on my friends Mac:

```
cd '/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw' -t         '   /Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/MarketCap_Scan.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
JWs-MacBook-Pro:~ JW$ cd '/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw' -t     '/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/MarketCap_Scan.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/MarketCap_Scan.py", line 33, in <module>
    api = [get_price(NewSymbolsList[i]),get_market_cap(NewSymbolsList[i])]
  File "/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/MarketCap_Scan.py", line 18, in get_price
    return _request(symbol, 'l1')
  File "/Users/JW/Desktop/market cap/MarketCap_Scan.py", line 15, in _request
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
JWs-MacBook-Pro:market cap JW$
```

An edit showing how I prepared the list to be iterated, (pretty standard I am guessing but thought it may be helpful):

```
symbols = open("symbolslist.txt")
readsymbols = symbols.read()
NewSymbolsList = readsymbols.split("\n")
```

Comment: A couple of questions:
- What version of Python are you using on each machine?
- What is the actual URL you're hitting on the mac?  A 400 means that Yahoo is telling you that you're doing something wrong.  Try printing it out before calling it.

Comment: @Mark Version is Python 2.7 on both machines. The error comes at the first url, so I am guessing it is syntax? Like I said it works fine on my computer. This is the url: ("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=%s") and the first symbol in the list is AAAE, I made sure there was no special characters in my list

Comment: Hmmm. So calling get_price('AAAE') and get_market_cap('AAAE') works as expected on my mac with python 2.7.  Does the request work if you call it directly?

Comment: @Mark The problem is my friend is located in a different region than me and he is even less inept than I. I wrote this for him with the hopes of him never having to edit it on his end (for the reason that it would be over complicated). Obviously if there is no other recourse then we will go that route.

Comment: I was thinking that it may have to do with the encoding, but I iterated over the list on my pc and it worked fine that is why I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's try this here.  I suspect that the problem that's being faced is white space related in the source file (perhaps a rogue \r?).  As an added note, I introduced a couple of with clause context managers to illustrate their usage for for the file handling.

```
import re
try:
    # py3
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # py2
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
    from urllib import urlencode

def _request(symbol, stat):
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=%s' % (symbol, stat)
    req = Request(url)
    resp = urlopen(req)
    return str(resp.read().decode('utf-8').strip())

def get_price(symbol):
    return _request(symbol, 'l1')

def get_market_cap(symbol):
    return _request(symbol, 'j1')

symbols = open("symbolslist.txt")
readsymbols = symbols.read()
NewSymbolsList = readsymbols.split("\n")

with open('symbolslist.txt') as ifp, open('intermediateresults.csv', 'a') as results_fp:
    for row in ifp:
        row = row.strip()
        api = [ get_price(row), get_market_cap(row) ]
        api = re.sub("\[\'|\'|\]", "", str(api))
        results_fp.write(str(row) +"," +str(api) +"\n")
        print row, api
```

On my computer, this prints:

```
Marks-MBP:~ mroberts$ python aa.py
AAAE 0.005, 171K
RENT 22.07, 262.4M
```

Comment: Actually, another thing that comes to mind is the /usr/local/bin/pythonw in your error output.  Have you tried using /usr/bin/python?

Comment: I will look into that tomorrow. I sent my friend a script that only calls the get_price command for one symbol. That works for him so I imagine you are right about the /r character. Unfortunately I wont know till tomorrow. I definitely appreciate your time and I did vote the answer up. If, as I suspect it will, it ends up being correct I will indicate that tomorroow with a green check mark. Thanks again @Mark Update, I sent it to my friend and it is indeed working, thank you very much for your time and now I have a solution for the future